# Using wildcard for subdomain in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax, express, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm using Express for my website and using credential xhr. I want to request to `http://example.com` from `http://admin.example.com` or `http://service1.example.com`, and this is my `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` part in express server:

```
// CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://*.example.com');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});
```

But when I try credential xhr from **http://admin.example.com** to **http://example.com**, it fails with:

> Fetch API cannot load `http://example.com/api/v1/authentication/signin`.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header has a value '`http://*.example.com`'
>   that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin
>   'http://admin.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. Have the
>   server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.

Looks like it causes from browser didn't understood what exactly `*.example.com` means, and refuse the request.

I want to request from these domains:

- example.com
- admin.example.com
- service1.example.com
- service2.example.com
- [anything].example.com

I'm using Fetch API for XHR, and set `credentials: true`. Is there a something that I missed? Any advice will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First off, IIRC; express documentation explicitly asks you not to use
>   lambda expression for the middlewares.

Coming to the CORS issue, a wildcard subdomain is not valid in the context. The support was added pretty recently (in [May '16](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/251)), and until then, [the CORS header must be an exact match of the domain name](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-cors-20140116/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header).

You can however, process your `req.hostname` value and add that to the response header:

```
// CORS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.hostname.endsWith('example.com')) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://' + req.hostname)
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type')
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
    }
    next()
})
```

Comment: I would tweak this to not use the hostname, rather you should use the `Origin` header. In your case, the hostname will be http://example.com, but the origin will be http://admin.example.com. Origin needs to match the exact protocol and domain (and also the port if non standard port). More Info: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Derric's comment. The other thing though is that origin headers can be spoofed, so this is not a secure solution.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.origin.endsWith('example.com')) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://' + req.headers.origin)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
  }
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another small adjustment here. We should also consider "protocol":

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.origin.endsWith('example.com')) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.origin)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
  }
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers suffer from a vulnerability, exposing the api to anyone that registers a badsiteexample.com domain name. i guess they tried to include both the main domain and subdomains in the check, but there is no need as if the api is on the main domain that would not be a cors request. and if you did need it, you should use two separate conditions for main domain and subdomains, or a regex.

`req.headers.origin.endsWith('.example.com') || req.headers.origin == 'example.com'`

`req.headers.origin.match(/(\.|^)example\.com$/)`

Comment: This is the only answer here that’s not incorrect in one way or another. Along with the `req.hostname.endsWith('example.com')` match in the other answers being wrong (for the reason this answer gives), the other answers show prefixing the protocol to the `req.headers.origin` value — and that’s wrong because the `req.headers.origin`  value already includes the protocol. So if you were to use the code from the other answers here as-is, you’d end up sending back, e.g., `http://http://example.com` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.